# DotNetOpenAuth TwitterConsumer "Failure looking up secret for consumer or token."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

Using DotNetOpenAuth 3.4.3.10103
when i call:

```
public static XDocument GetUpdates(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken) {
IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(GetFriendTimelineStatusEndpoint, accessToken);
return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
}
```

I keep getting "Failure looking up secret for consumer or token." on PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend the access key is good and I can see it in debug on the twitter.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ConsumerBase you've initialized and passed in needs to have an `IConsumerTokenManager` instance that has a consumer key and consumer secret set on it.  Be sure you have that.  The token manager must also know about the access token you've passed into `PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend` and know the associated access token secret.

Comment: my bad, i wasn't updating the Access token I had when twitter gave me a new one.